# Locally bounded vs bounded on compacts

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $f$ be a scalar-valued function on $X$ (not necessarily continuous).

Then $f$ is called *locally bounded* if for every $x\in X$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f|_{U}$ is bounded. This condition is equivalent to existence of an open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$, such that $f|_{U_i}$ is bounded, for every $i\in I$.

It is easy to see that every locally bounded function is *bounded on every compact set* in $X$.

Moreover, the converse is also true if we additionally assume that $X$ is locally compact or metrizable. In the former case, it is trivial; since every convergent sequence in a metric space is a compact set, the negation of local boundedness on a metric space implies negation of boundeness on compacts.

A class of topological spaces that includes metrizable and locally compact spaces if the class of *compactly generated* spaces. It is natural to ask whether the property holds for this bigger class.

> Let $X$ be a compactly generated Tychonoff topological space and let $f$ be a scalar function on $X$, such that $f|_{K}$ is bounded, for every compact $K\subset X$. Is it true that $f$ is locally bounded?

Note that I have included Tychonoff into the hypothesis in order to eliminate some patological spaces which I don't have any intuition about. Of course it would be excellent if one can go with merely Hausdorff axiom.

Comment: Note that your argument for metrizable spaces in fact works for any first-countable space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false.  For instance, let $X=\bigvee I_n$ be a wedge sum of infinitely many intervals.  Every compact subset of $X$ is contained in a union of finitely many of the $I_n$, so any function $f$ that is bounded on each $I_n$ is bounded on compact sets.  Such a function need not be locally bounded at the wedge point $p$.  For instance, $f$ might be given by $f(p)=0$ and $f(x)=n$ if $x\in I_n\setminus\{p\}$.

Comment: Thank you! I think it should be added that $X$ is compactly generated as a quotient of a locally compact space $\mathbb{N}\times [0,1]$.